# c# apagar drawstring em picturebox

Tags: c#, string, delete, picturebox, drawing

Tenho uma pictureBox onde o usuario a cada clique do mouse insere um texto em cima de uma imagem em um pictureBox. Ele insere varios textos em varios pontos da imagem, o texto inserido é pego de checkboxes.

Usando este código

```
 private void pictureBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox2.Image);
        var mouseEventArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
        if (mouseEventArgs != null) textBox1.Text = "X= " + mouseEventArgs.X + " Y= " + mouseEventArgs.Y;

        g.DrawString(texto, new Font("Verdana", 30F, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Red, new PointF(e.X * pictureBox2.Image.Width / pictureBox2.Width -30,
e.Y * pictureBox2.Image.Height / pictureBox2.Height -90));
        pictureBox2.Refresh();
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

O que não estou conseguindo é deletar os textos. Gostaria que ele pudesse deletar qualquer um que ele inseriu em qualquer ordem. Pensei em uma espécie de CTRL+Z porém isso iria deletando um por um, se ele ja inseriu 5, e quer apagar apenas o primeiro, o ctrl+z já não serviria.

Pensei em uma espécie de borracha, que ele fosse mechendo o mouse por cima do texto que ele inseriu e fosse apagando, sem apagar a imagem de fundo. Ou pela propria checkbox que ele clicou para escolher qual texto escrever, se clicar na checkbox denovo o drawstring que corresponde aquele texto da checkbox deletasse.

É possivel deletar esses drawstring? O jeito mais facil possivel, sou iniciante.

Comment: conforme na outra pergunta, tenho esse form que fiz há muito tempo, veja se ajuda: https://pastebin.com/qCs9RF6v Obs. Tem o código do arquivo de designer e depois o codigo do form em si

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer uma borracha, utilizei o seguinte comando:

```
    private void Borracha(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int t = int.Parse(tam.ToString());
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(pic1.Image);
        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Magenta), e.X - (t / 2), e.Y - (t / 2), t, t);
        Bitmap b = (Bitmap)pic1.Image;
        b.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta);
        pic1.Image = b;
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Meu amigo, muito obrigado novamente, Funcionou perfeitamente. A unica coisa que gostaria é q aparecesse o tamanho da barracha, ela apaga certinho mas o usuario nao sabe o tamanho do circulo da borracha. Da pra fazer aparecer uma borda ou pintar o circulo que é a borracha?? Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: acho q pra aparecer uma borda, você teria que usar o graphics do form, e um DrawEllipse junto desse código, ou alterar o cursor, mas eu não cheguei a fazer isso